# PHP and the GD library

Tags: php

I'm using GD to change the font on user posted comments. What I have so far works for a *single* post but what I need are *all* of the posts output into a single image. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need to post some code..

Comment: although why are you displaying user posted comments as an image rather than as text?

Comment: Mark, I am only using GD to change the font in the posts. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: This sounds more like something you should be doing with CSS - or is this more specific?

Comment: I'd prefer text to an image. BTW.

Comment: If CSS is the way to go, I'm open to that but can someone give me an example?

Comment: I can't for the life of me fathom why you'd want to use an image to display text instead of just using text.  Also, why not just generate an image for each comment and then combine the images into one final image?

Comment: As others have said don't use an image. Try using CSS or something like sIFR so that they can still copy and paste. This will also cut down greatly on the amount of bandwidth you'll be using, etc.

Comment: @siride - this is exactly what I want to do. I want to string the images together -- into a single image. If CSS is better then I'll use CSS but this is not a normal font that will be found on most users' systems and is why I used GD.

Comment: @blcArmadillo -  I think this may be a much better alternative. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use a custom font that won't be available on users' computers?  Unless it has special characters (math symbols, IPA symbols, etc.), there's really no good reason to do this.  It kind of goes against the point of how web-browsers are supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, the font is non-negotiable and is a requirement. I don't have a choice here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use GD. Instead, use CSS to control fonts. For instance, output your comment inside a div with a class:

```
<div class="comment"><?=$comment_text></div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
div.comment { font-family: "Courier New"; }
div.comment * { font-family: inherit !important; }
```

What this will do is force the font inside your comment to Courier New, even if the comment contains HTML that uses the `<font>` tag or specifies font in a `style` attribute.

The first style rule says that all `<div>` elements with the class `comment` will use Courier New as its font. The second rule tells all descendants of that div (ie. any elements within the div) to inherit the font styling, and `!important` tells the browser that that rule should overrule any other `font-family` rule on the element.

---

**Update based on your comment:**

If you want to use a font that you think most users won't have, you can still solve this with CSS, by specifying an [`@font-face`](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) declaration and hosting the font file on your server.

Take a look at [Bulletproof @font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) for an example of how you can use `@font-face` in a cross-browser way. There's also a [@font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) that you can use.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the snippet. Unless I'm missing something, this won't work because the TTF I am using is one that will not be on the users' system. Your thoughts?

Comment: Most fonts are proprietary, and unless you have the copyright holders consent, you can't distribute the font file.

Comment: @jmz I understand that, I'm making the assumption that @Jim is able to distribute the font. Anyways, the point of this is not legality but technique.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the font face trick. I didn't know that. For the debate here, this is a free, redistributable font so I should be just fine there. I tend to be more pragmatic on programming and if I have to implement something that is going to require a couple of hours of work to keep these comments in a strict CSS environment over using a font face tag, I will always choose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Jim, you'd better stop using GD and look at the `<font>` tag in HTML docs. Or let server eat resources and users eat traffic.

If you really need to stick to GD for some reason, just give as some code. In particular, MySQL query till image output.

P.S. *Everything is possible.*

Comment: Don't use the <font> tag, use CSS.

Comment: Thanks Andrejs. I don't have to use GD and I have noticed that it is WAY slow while compiling the posts. I'd love to have another alternative such as someone has suggested sIFR.